# Darker Frame Labels

Tags: labeling, frame

When I apply `FontFamily-> "Time New Roman"` to the frame labels, they turned blurred. Is there any way to make it darker? Notice that I need "Time New Roman" in any case and I have tried "Black", but it fails. Thanks!

Comment: `“...but it fails.”` How exactly does it fail? What is the error you get? What code have you used to get such error? Please, update your post with this information, rather than provide such information as a comment. Thanks!

Comment: No, error! It just look the same as without using "black".

Comment: `TicksStyle->Bold`

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 5/final:**

Using [`MaTeX`](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX)

```
Needs["MaTeX`"];
xx = MaTeX["x", Magnification -> 7];
sinx = MaTeX["\\text{sin(x)}", Magnification -> 3];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {xx, sinx}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: matexplot]

**Edit 4/next-to-last edit:**

You can use [`Colors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Colors.html) and the option [`Bold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Bold.html)

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 23, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Black,
     Bold], 
   Style["sin(x)", 13, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Black, Bold]},
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: bold]

```
$Version
```

> `"13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
    Black], 
   Style["sin(x)", 18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Black]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: sin]

Is the above acceptable?

**Edit:**

Implementing Greek letters

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["χ", 23, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
    Black], 
   Style["sin(χ)", 23, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Black]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: sin2]

**Edit 2:**

Taking the comment into consideration and reducing the size of the font.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 13, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
    Black], 
   Style["sin(x)", 13, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Black]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: sin3]

**Edit 3:**

Taking the version specification into account.

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"
> ```

I am doing one large and one small font. Still clear, the only difference is the size

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 23, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
    Black], Style["sin(x)", 13, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
    Black]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: v12]

Comment: But this is due to using a large font size. Can you try with 13, please?

Comment: @SciJewel have a look at the updated version. it is not due to the size. the size is due to the size to make visible that there are no distortions. with smaller size, still black. no blur, just smaller.

Comment: I use Mathematica 12.3

Comment: @SciJewel with all due respect, how was I supposed to know that? It is neither explicitly in the title nor in the OP. Let me grab my other laptop and try with `V12`.

Comment: I am sorry not to mention this. I thought I am already using the latest version, but not.

Comment: @SciJewel that's fine. I updated with the plot from `V12`. As you can see the only difference again is the size and nothing else. No blur, no distortion and black color. Plus the commands are the same in `V12` and `V13`.

Comment: @SciJewel you might want to have a look now with the updates on `V12` and the use of [`Bold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Bold.html)

Comment: why in the second last, the small font on Y-axis is a blur. That's my concern.

Comment: @SciJewel you are a bit vague. In the sense, that you say cannot be quantified. In other words, I don't see anything blurred. In addition to that, I provided an alternative with the use of [`Bold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Bold.html) so again I don't see what your concern is.

Comment: Don't you see the label on Y-axis in the last plot is blurred compared to that on X-axis? The only difference is boldface.

Comment: @SciJewel no I don't to be honest. I am sorry. I added a fifth way for completeness. Please, take into consideration that you have five approaches. With a bit of experimentation and some combinations, you should be able to produce a plot to your liking.

Comment: @SciJewel Again, my apologies but this is as much as I can help.

Comment: Sure, I appreciate your help!